# Trying to return values in a user specified range

Tags: python

I am trying to print all values within a user specified range. However when I enter numbers the program does not print the values.

```
print "This module will return all numbers in a specified range."

v = range(-100000, 100001)

lo = int(raw_input("Please enter the beginning of the range:"))

hi = int(raw_input("Please enter the end of the range: "))

def filter_range():

    if lo < v[0] and hi > v[-1]:
        print v[lo: hi]

    elif lo < v[0]:
        print "That is out of range."


    if hi > v[-1]:
        print "That is out of range."

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filter_range()
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create your range `v`, the indices for items start at 0, not -100000. Therefore, when you

```
print v[lo: hi]
```

you are not actually printing the values asked for. For example, if I ask for 0 to 10, I get -100000 to -99990. Why not create the `range` only when needed?

```
print(list(range(lo, hi)))
```

This saves on all the memory you fill up with 200002 integers, and you don't need to test if `hi` and `lo` are in some range, which was causing your other problem (per samrap's answer).

Note that in earlier versions of 2.x, you will need to write `print range(lo, hi)`.

Comment: You are mixing Python 2.x and Python 3.x print statements. Also, `range(lo,hi)` is already a list so you don't need the `list` function. Use `print range(lo,hi)`

Comment: [range in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange) is what an xrange is in Python 2 - not a list.  So Jon's concern about memory is not relevant in Python 3, but list() must be used when a list is needed.

Comment: But since the code has `print` and not `print()` statements, this is Python 2 not Python 3. Giving Python 3 code that doesn't work in Python 2 when the OP is clearly using Python 2 is not a good thing to do.

Comment: It will work in both 3.x and recent 2.x releases, although the list call is unnecessary in the latter. I have edited to comment for earlier 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you want to change this line:

```
if lo < v[0] and hi > v[-1]:
    print v[lo: hi]
```

To this:

```
if lo > v[0] and hi < v[-1]:
    print v[lo: hi]
```

Output:

```
[-99999, -99998, -99997, -99996, -99995, -99994, -99993...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use the values given as the indices per your own instructions. Nor should you store such a large vector. See the revised code below.

```
print "This module will return all numbers in a specified range."

allowed_lo = -100000
allowed_hi = 100000

lo = int(raw_input("Please enter the beginning of the range:"))
hi = int(raw_input("Please enter the end of the range: "))

def filter_range():
    if lo < allowed_lo or hi > allowed_hi:
        print "That is out of range."
    else:
        return range(lo, hi+1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print filter_range()
```

Something that is a little more fun would be to use list comprehension to do this.

```
v = range(-100000,100001)

lo = int(raw_input("Please enter the beginning of the range:"))
hi = int(raw_input("Please enter the end of the range: "))

def filter_range():
    if lo < allowed_lo or hi > allowed_hi:
        print "That is out of range."
    else:
        print [x for x in v if lo <= x <= hi]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print filter_range()
```